# Custom validation for a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to add custom validation to a form, lets says add article form.

I was expecting something like `hook_FORM_ID_validate()` to handle this, but cannot find anything relavant in the API documentation.

What is the way to add custom validation to a form?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can add any number of validation functions to any form in [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) like so:

```
function mymodule_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // There will already be some validate handlers added so you need to add to the
  // array rather than overwrite it.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_article_form_validate';

  // As mentioned above you can add as many as you want
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_article_form_validate_2';
}

function mymodule_article_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Random example, if the title is 'test' throw an error
  if ($form_state['values']['title'] == 'test') {
    form_set_error('title', 'Title cannot be "test"');
  }
}
```

Comment: Suppose i've added custom form validation to a form which have already 2 validation function. Then which is get first preference in drupal 7?

Comment: Which ever is first in the array @Guru

Comment: If the form is user_registration_form, then it always keeps "[#validate] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_account_form_validate
            [1] => user_validate_picture
        )". Suppose i'm going to add custom validation. Then it should be like this "[#validate] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_account_form_validate
            [1] => user_validate_picture
            [2] => user_register_validate
        )". But i want to run "user_register_validate" function at first.

Comment: For other fields, you got to use: `if ($form_state['values']['field_custom']['und'][0]['value'] == 'Error') { //throw error }`

Comment: how to set validation for size, extension in this manner?  And one more question, if there is ajax functionality like"upload" and "remove" how we handle validation for this?

Answer (score 6):

You should use `hook_form_alter` and add your function to the [`#validate`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#validate) property.