# How do I add custom validations to Webform?

Tags: webforms, forms

I have created the country and state fields with the Webform module, and I want to add a field validation for the state field when user select US as country.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form

Comment: Not necessarily.  The linked question is more generic, this is specific to Webform which has different options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module should add the features you need.

> This module adds an extra tab to each webform node, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your webform components. You can create
>   one or more of the predefined validation rules, and select which
>   webform component(s) should be validated against those. By using the
>   hooks provided by this module, you can also define your own validation
>   rules in your own modules.

If you need something more in depth or with possibly more control then check out the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form) linked to in the question comments.

Answer (score 7):

Make use of the validate function in hook_form_alter:

```
 if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_14') {  
    $form['#validate'][] = 'cork_creation_validate_custom';  
 }

function cork_creation_validate_custom($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+$/', $form_state['values']['submitted']['name'])) {
            // $form['submitted'][$key]['#attributes']['class'] = 'error';
            form_set_error('name', t('Please enter alphabets only for Name.'));
 } 

  }
```

Comment: This is described on the doc page [Custom coding: Adding advanced validation or submit code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1291574), which has more details.

Comment: @colan the webform module do not adhere 100% tends to implement  its own solutions, so it's good to know it works here.