# How to validate a file upload field added to a form using hook_form_alter?

Tags: 6, forms

I am trying to add a file upload field to all story node forms. I tested the code and I am successfully getting the file upload field  on the form.

```
$form['my_file_upload'] = array(
    '#attributes' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#description' => t('Image should be of minimum 50x50px width and should be of type png or jpg'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#size' => 48,
  '#weight' => 4,
);
```

Now the question is How do I validate the file and also how do I retrieve the file after it has passed validation?

(Site runs on Drupal 6)

Comment: why dont you use cck?

Comment: I am not not sure on how to use CCK in this scenario.

Comment: what are you trying to do...

Comment: I am trying to retrieve an image from a node create form and then use it in my code.

Comment: retrive an image and what do you want to do with..

Comment: I want to display the image in the teaser view of the post.

Comment: you should add a field in the content type and then use that to display in the teaser that would be a better process. add the cck module and the cck imagefiled add that to the content type and then use the manage diplay to add that in the teaser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7175/discussion-between-binny-and-mohammed-shameem)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is what the Upload module does: In [upload_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!upload!upload.module/function/upload_form_alter/6) (an implementation of `hook_form_alter()`), it adds the form element to the node edit forms, and in the form submission handler it adds to the form ([upload_node_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!upload!upload.module/function/upload_node_form_submit/6)), it handles the uploaded files. With [_upload_file_limits()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!upload!upload.module/function/_upload_file_limits/6), it checks the user didn't reach the assigned quota; with [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6), it checks the file passes the validators, and saves the file.

The Upload module, once enabled, allows you to enable the file upload for the content types. For example, for the Page content type, you can enable it at admin/content/node-type/page.

[image: screenshot]

In the node edit form, the form element the Upload module adds appears as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

If the Upload module is already enabled, and you need a upload form element more, than you should use the CCK module.

Answer (score 1):

question is already asked here, [Custom validation for a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form)

but still solving your problem, you can add validate method in form alter .

```
$form[#validate][] = 'function_name_callback';
```

and then you can validate the form submission in that function

```
function function_name_callback($form, $form_state){
//validate here
}
```