# Make Exposed form view content only appears to logged in user

Tags: 7, views, users

I have created a view and exposed that form.
I want when user click on exposed form search button it should show register or login form if user is anonymous otherwise it should show result.

After user logged in it should get back to result
drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - use hook_form_alter.

1. Add custom validate function on your exposed form
2. Use function user_is_logged_in in your validate function
3. If it return false, use drupal_goto, for redirect user to the login or register page.

Comment: what will be the validate function ?

Comment: Validate function for form. You can see info about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375616/how-to-use-form-validation-in-drupal-7 and here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form

Comment: will it return back the result page after successfully logged in

Comment: I tried to validate it with !user_is_logged_in. But it is automatically redirecting me to login page before I click on apply. as my exposed form is on front page