# Webform validation with multiple conditions

Tags: webforms, forms

I am wondering if it's possible to verify a webform with the following type of condition:

If a text field contains "stringA", then a numeric field must also have a value of at least 20.

Or, if that same text field contains "stringB", then the numeric field must have a value of at least 19.

So - I need a validation pattern of (("this and this") or ("that and that")).

I have Webform Validation installed as a module - can it do this kind of thing?

Comment: I am not sure if Webform Validation can but you can write your own [validation handlers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form#22964).