# Disable publish and unpublish options in VBO on the main content view for one role

Tags: views

We have a situation where a user that has a role without permissions to administer nodes is able to bypass that restriction and use the VBO widget to mass-publish or -unpublish nodes on the system content view at `/admin/content`.

My thought was to unset the `publish` and `unpublish` values from the select box definition, but after debugging with `hook_form_alter`, I discovered I could not see the element in the form definition.

I next tried to look at the view object with `hook_view_pre_view`, but I don't see it there either?

How can I selective alter the VBO widget? We don't want to get rid of it altogether, but we can't have people without permissions publishing and unpublishing nodes.

**Edit:** I found [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/how-can-i-hide-delete-option-from-operations-in-admin-drupal-7), but it only explains how to delete those operations altogether, for everyone, which is not what we want. We only want them gone for people who don't have permission to publish or unpublish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) contains a sub module called ACTIONS PERMISSIONS:

> A module called actions_permissions is included in the package. This
>   module generates a permission for each action, and VBO honors those
>   permissions before showing or executing the corresponding actions.
>   This is useful if you want to provide your VBO to several groups of
>   users with different privileges: the same view will accommodate those
>   different groups, showing to each the actions that they are permitted
>   to see.

[image]