# How do I skip validation for node form element?

Tags: hooks, forms

I have a content type having 10 fields that are all required. How do I skip validation for some fields? Is there any hook/function that allow me to do this?

Comment: Do you want that to decide after submission or before submission?

Comment: After save button clicked.

Comment: you can edit the required field and change it's setting.

Comment: @WaQaR Ali fields are depend on other value, so I cant not change this form settings.

Comment: then you should follow the *hook_form_alter* as written in below answer.

Comment: Same question here how can I skip validation for a specific form element e.g field_xyz ?

Answer (score 1):

I consider that by

> How do I skip validation

you mean "make the fields not compulsory" (UI level)

If that is the case then you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and change the 
`['#required']`
setting, for any form element, to 
`FALSE`.

Keep in mind that [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) is a generic hook invoked by any form in your site (performance issue) alternative you may use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to "to talk" to a specific form. Hope that helps.

If you want to make the validation on a different level, you have to [write your own validation handlers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form) (`['#validate']`) or override Drupal's, like `node_form_validate`

Answer (score 1):

For deciding and skipping some fields after submit follow the following steps.

Step 1: Perform [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add a custom function in **$form['#validate]** array, remember your custom validate function must add on 0th key of the array.

Step 2: Perform your calculation and find on which fields you want to perform the validations, and set them in **$form['#limit_validation_errors']**.

I hope this will help you for the skipping validation.

Comment: I have to skip some required fields value based on other required value.
This will checked run time once user clicked on save button.