# How to programmatically check whether field on form has changed in hook_form_alter

Tags: forms, rules

In rules you have the ability to check whether a field in a form has been changed by negating node-unchanged:field-xyz = 123.

I want to check whether a field has changed programmatically with the $form and $form_state.

How would you do this?

Comment: Hey hey, what have you tried so far? And what is your exact question? Please update your post to provide specific problems we can help you to solve.

Comment: Compare the `$form` default value vs the `$form_state` value. If they are not equal, then there was a change. You'll want to do this inside a custom form validate or submit function. Use `hook_form_alter` to add your custom validate or submit function. See: [Custom validation for a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form) as an example.